# Discord.py SQLite database inventory

Tags: python, sqlite, search, discord.py

So I am creating a discord bot in discord.py, and I need some help. I am creating a currency system, in which the player can hold money and items. I figured out how to add money to people, however I need help with the inventory system. I used the following code to create two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    itemid bigserial NOT NULL,
    title text NULL,
    description text NULL,
    rarity int2 NULL,
    emoji text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "items-primarykey" PRIMARY KEY (itemid)
);

CREATE TABLE useritems (
    userid int8 NOT NULL,
    gildid int8 NOT NULL,
    itemid int8 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT useritems_unique UNIQUE (userid, gildid),
    CONSTRAINT useritems_fk FOREIGN KEY (itemid) REFERENCES items(itemid)
);
```

Example for items table:

```
itemid   |   title   |   description   |   rarity   |   emoji
---------------------------------------------------------------
12         cookie      a yummy treat         4         :cookie:
```

Example for useritems table:

```
   userid   |      gildid     |  itemid
------------------------------------
695848392012  3829483729391      12
```

I was wondering how to make it so that a user can access their inventory. I want it something like:

```
   userId   |    title    |   description    |   rarity    |    emoji
------------------------------------------------------------------------
695848392012    cookie       a yummy treat!        4            :cookie:
```

The rarity in this case is an integer. For example if `rarity` is 3, that means the amount is 3. Does anyone know anything that can help me?
I was also wondering if I can get a variable for userid, title, description, rarity, and emoji

Answer (score 0):

From the useritems table, you can `SELECT itemid from useritems WHERE userid = ?` (? being a placeholder) and retrieve the item ids. Then you can query the items table to get the item info (`SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemid = ?`)